# jQuery add number of rows to the table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like this

```
<table id="user-data">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Contact Number</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now all the fields for the fields like Name, Email and Contact Number is populating from database. Before this I was  getting only a single row of content. So I made my script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = $('<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"contact-number\"></td></tr>');
    $('table#user-data').append(html);
</script>
```

This was adding the single row in the table without any problem. But now I want to add more then single row at a time and the row number will change every time. So can someone tell me how to add given number of rows to the table dynamically? Any help and suggestions will be really appreceable. Thanks

**Update**
I am getting the number of rows in my jQuery. Lets say it is in a variable called Length.

Comment: *"populating from database"* isn't helpful at all. What's the structure of data? an array, json, json array..? you should iterate accordingly.

Comment: In the example above, your `var html` seems to be constructed independent of any data (the data you mention is being populated from the database). Anyhow, how about your wrap the code which populates a row and iterate over the collection your receive from the database?

Clutching at straws here, a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: I am getting the number in jQuery

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, assume you have the number of records in a variable called `length`.

You can add that many number of rows as follows:

```
var html;
for(i=0; i<length; i++){
   html += '<tr><td><input type="text" name="name"></td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td><td><input type="text" name="contact-number"></td></tr>';
}
$('table#user-data').append(html);
```

*Side notes:*

- It's a good practice to avoid `DOM` manipulation inside loops if possible. You can
  concatenate the `HTML` and append it all at once in this case.
- You don't have to escape the quotes as long as you're using a different quote inside the string

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your current code in a for loop which will append a new row to the table for each record that you are iterating over.

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var html = $('<tr><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"email\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"contact-number\"></td></tr>');
    $('table#user-data').append(html);
}
```

You can then use `i+1` as the value for the row number

Comment: If you can post your datasource, I'll revise my answer so that it fits for your situation...it's really just a stab in the dark right now

Comment: The comment option is there for a reason. And you seems to have enough rep to comment, asking for more information. stabbing in the dark right  is a bad practise, because users will keep coming back with such dark questions without enough info.

Comment: I appreciate your input, but this is a legitimate answer to his question...which is why I chose not to put it in the question comment.

Comment: *"stabbing in the dark"* isn't legitimate...:)

Comment: This could answer to the question so it don't have to be put in comments

Comment: @Ahmad when it was posted, the question was unclear and unanswerable.  btw, please tell me whats `data.length` ??

Comment: Okay, `data.length` is the number of elements in object `data`